# Click and get table data of certain cell

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where each row have a button to view a record, when I click that button I want to send the record id of that row and store it in a variable.

Here is what I have so far

```
foreach($result as $row) 
{

        echo "<td> <form method='post'><input name='viewticket' type='submit' id='viewticket' value='View Ticket' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger'/></form></td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['isopen']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td> </tr>";

}

if($_POST['viewticket']){
    $theid= //not sure how it would work
}
```

**Here is how the UI looks like:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zmE3.jpg

Comment: Add, inside the form, a hidden input with the ticket ID. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

Comment: Other alternative would be using a get request instead of POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert a

```
"<input type='hidden' name='selectedID' value='" + $row['id'] + "'/>"
```

into the form, then you have the ID in $_POST['selectedID']:

```
foreach($result as $row) 
    {

        echo "<td> <form method='post'><input name='viewticket' type='submit' id='viewticket' value='View Ticket' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger'/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='selectedID' value='" + $row['id'] + "'/></form></td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['isopen']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td> </tr>";
    }

}

if($_POST['viewticket']){
    echo $_POST['selectedID'];
}
```

Comment: @QasimAhmed consider accepting this answer :) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: sorry thought i clicked it :p

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative is using a GET request instead of POST.

So, your code would look something like this:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
?>
  <td>
    <a href="?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
      <input name='viewticket' type='submit' id='viewticket' value='View Ticket' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger'/>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['isopen'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['title'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
<?php
}

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $theid = $_GET['id'];
}
```